# Create install USB with specific packages and configuration or have 1 server to define all packages and config

Tags: system-installation, package-management

So I have been having problems creating my custom Ubuntu Installation USB.
I have used the LiveCD, I have used UCK, I have used Cubic Custom Iso creator.
And I can't get it to work. So I started doing research on google and askubuntu but I could only find information that was very dated.

Let me explain what I want. I work for a company that is moving from Windows to Ubuntu. On over 50 laptops and computers. I started installing them 1 by 1 including all the software and I thought it would be faster if I could have all our software prepacked with the install. So I tried to create a custom USB. But I failed so many times.

We want to have update notifications and screensaver off. We want chrome with Ublock Origin instead of Firefox. We want QGIS and all required packages for QGIS. We also want Java and Minecraft installed by default.

I have also thought of doing something else to achieve this. I thought it might have be possible to have 1 server manage all the clients. Something like a Windows Terminal Server but I can't find anything like that, that is still being updated or is updated to atleast 14.04.

Is there any way I can get a explanation on how to create a custom USB with packages and configuration. Or how I can setup something like a Terminal Server for Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Look into Puppet or Landscape, or if I read the penultimate para right, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ThinClients

Answer (score 0):

I know how to use aptik and i use it often when one of my customers need to clone a desktop to a laptop etc... What exactly is not working or needed? You have the right idea to clone that many Ubuntu PCs, All you need to do is setup the host PC exactly you want and then use aptik http://www.howtogeek.com/206454/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-apps-and-ppas-in-ubuntu-using-aptik/
And use the resulting usb on all of them  or you can copy the backup files aptik makes it to as many USB's as you want. OR try systemback https://launchpad.net/systemback  to take a snapshot of your current setup or host all set up and create a bootable usb backup of it which can also be put on unlimited usb's too. I've had luck with both. Its very helpful to us if you let us know your Ubuntu version etc too since programs sometimes work on one release and does not on another.  Good luck.